# Native mobile, user content editable

Tags: mobile, interface, user-generated-content, native-app

I was wondering because I can't seem to find any examples of a good native design for modifying user content;

I'm an Android developer and I have a dedicated job to build one app for our company. For now it has been mostly made for reading and posting content, however it seems required that we allow editing of content.

The content is quite simple f/e you have a forum where you can upload attachments. These attachments are shown in the post as width of the full screen and can be swiped/scrolled horizontally.

What would be a good example of allowing the user (or a moderator) to edit content like this.

The content being: The text he typed, which is plaintext so it should be opened in an EditText element (input).
Sometimes, there is the possibility to also add a title, same goes for this.

The pictures/files attached, these can be of various types, if not an image or video they're displayed with an file icon.

Images can be removed or others can be uploaded.

I was thinking it would be best to handle this on a different activity (page).

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more on `allowing the user (or a moderator) to edit content`?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation, I don't know what it should look like, but I don't mind it being in a dialog, new activity or w/e. It now describes what should be editable.

Comment: I don't get exactly the meaning of your question, maybe is it because I'm not an amazingly good english speaker. Do you mean that you want the edit to be done on an other view ? (the same way you do an edit on the SE forums for example ?)

Comment: Does not have to be, I'm just wondering if anyone has examples/ideas how it should be.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or mockups to get a feeling of the available / used space of the elements? I'm a huge fan of front-end editing and would place an "x" button for deletion next to every image etc., but not sure how suitable that is for a 4" mobile device screen.

Comment: You could think about how facebook content looks, that is the closest. Can't post since it might change soon and I don't own it.
Like the first screenshot here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=nl

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way I can think of is if the user has edit permissions, give them the ability to click on an element, receive a menu or option to edit, and then allow them to edit in place, WYSIWYG style.  When the edit is done, give them a means to save/exit the edit mode and return back to the browse display seamlessly.  As for the attachments, I recommend having some kind of overlay icon to indicate a replacement/delete of a file or image during the edit mode.